# How to mv and adopt target directory permissions

Tags: permissions, rename

How do I move a file such that the file adopts the target directory permissions?
Surely this is an incredibly common scenario.... any help appreciated.

Comment: That is actually very uncommon. For example, directories that you can access have execute permission, so this would systematically make the file executable. Do you really want to set permissions and not ownership? [What problem are you trying to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sort of wrapper would handle this unusual scenario.  The example has been tested as working but takes minimal options (no traditional /bin/mv options can be passed on the command line).  Save below to a script and execute it (either with `bash script` or `chmod +x script` then run it `./script`):

```
#!/bin/bash

helpusage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 targetdir files"
    exit
}

getperms() {
    /usr/bin/stat --printf="%a" "$1"
}
getowner() {
    /usr/bin/stat --printf="%U" "$1"
}
getgroup() {
    /usr/bin/stat --printf="%G" "$1"
}
if [[ $# -ge 2 ]]
then
    if [[ -d "$1" ]]
    then
        targetdir=$1
        shift
    else
        helpusage
    fi
else
    helpusage
fi

td_perms=$(getperms "$targetdir")
td_owner=$(getowner "$targetdir")
td_group=$(getgroup "$targetdir")

/bin/mv --target-directory="$targetdir" "$@" && \
for file in "$@"
do
    file="$targetdir/$file"
    /bin/chmod "$td_perms" "$file"
    /bin/chown "$td_owner":"$td_group" "$file"
done
```